# git commit message in one line?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

Is there a way to show the whole commit message in one line?

Here is my commit message:

```
git log -1

here this is a change
it is a empty change
```

Output:

```
here this is a change it is a empty change
```

Comment: Try to add --oneline?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
git show -s --format='%B' <Commit ID> | tr -d '\n'; echo
```

Reference:
[Print git commits body lines joined in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538665/print-git-commits-body-lines-joined-in-one-line)